# pandas documentation example for append does not work (pandas.DataFrame.append)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I copied the example from the pandas documentation for the append method, but it isn't working for me.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
df
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))
df.append(df2)
print(df)
```

outputs:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

and not:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
0  5  6
1  7  8
```

What are possible reasons for this? Where is my mistake?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `df = df.append(df2)` ? or `print(df.append(df2))` ? Meaning append returns a new DataFrame

Comment: You have to assign it back to your `df` variable

Comment: Thank you @DanielMesejo. So easy :D
But why is that not in the documentation?

Comment: Virtually all Pandas operations return a new data frame rather than being applied in place, some support the inplace flag to override this. The docs are written as shell commands not scripts so they are not incorrect, just different. The last line of the example in the docs is equivalent to print(df.append(df2)) in a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas `append` method returns a concatenated dataframe, it does not concatenate the two dataframes inplace. This means `df.append(df2)` does not modify the original `df` but instead returns a new dataframe. The pandas example is in IPython and is correct. This should work:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))

df = df.append(df2)

print(df)
```

This will print out

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
0  5  6
1  7  8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=list('AB'))
df
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 6], [7, 8]], columns=list('AB'))
**df = df.append(df2)**
print(df)
```

the only thing you were missing is assining the new matrix to df, or a new variable. also, you could print it with print(df.append(df2))